# max of date in a query in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need help with writing part of query. Here's what I have

```
create table first_table(empid [varchar] (10) primary key not null,
DateInserted Datetime)
insert into  first_table('1001','2012-02-13');
insert into  first_table('1002','2013-02-13');
insert into  first_table('1003','2014-02-11');
insert into  first_table('1004','2012-02-13');
insert into  first_table('2001','2012-02-12');
insert into  first_table('2002','2014-02-13');
insert into  first_table('5001','2014-02-13');

create table second_table(empid [varchar] (10) not null, CompanyID  [varchar] (10) not null)
insert into  second_table('1001','1');
insert into  second_table('1002','1');
insert into  second_table('1003','1');
insert into  second_table('1004','1');
insert into  second_table('2001','2');
insert into  second_table('2002','2');
insert into  second_table('5001','5');

create table valid_companies(CompanyID  [varchar] (10) not null)
insert into valid_companies('1');
insert into valid_companies('2');
```

I want to select records from first_table that are valid_companies and with max date.
query should print

```
1003,1,2014-02-11
2002,2,2014-02-13
```

I am able to get

```
select DateInserted,ni.empID
      ,CompanyID
       from 
      [dbo].[second_table] vw 
      inner join [dbo].[first_table] ni on ni.EmpID=vw.EmpID
 where TagValue in(
SELECT DISTINCT [CompanyID]
FROM [dbo].[Valid_Companies]
)
```

. How to include max(DateInserted) in this query

Thx
R

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select e.empid, ec.CompanyID,
   Max(e.DateInserted) LatestDate
from second_table ec
   join first_table e
      on e.empid = ec.empid 
   join valid_companies v
      on v.CompanyID = ec.CompanyID  
group by e.empid, ec.CompanyID
```